# Deadlock between Cooperating objects

Tags: java, multithreading

While going through the `Java Concurrency in Practice` I came across the below code **Deadlock**, which demonstrated how a `deadlock` can occur between `cooperating objects`. If one thread calls `getImage()` and at the same time another calls `setLocation()` it can lead to deadlock due to `lock ordering`. To solve this we use `Open calls` **No Deadlock** below . My doubt is inside `setLocation()`in **No Deadlock** why are we doing `synchronized(this)` again inside the already `synchronized` method ? Isn't the `synchronized` method already `synchronized` on `this`? How are we preventing the deadlock using the 2nd example?

**DeadLock**

```
class Taxi {
        @GuardedBy("this")
        private Point location, destination;
        private final Dispatcher dispatcher;

        public Taxi(Dispatcher dispatcher) {
            this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
        }

        public synchronized Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public synchronized void setLocation(Point location) {
            this.location = location;
            if (location.equals(destination))
                dispatcher.notifyAvailable(this);
        }
    }

    class Dispatcher {
        @GuardedBy("this")
        private final Set<Taxi> taxis;
        @GuardedBy("this")
        private final Set<Taxi> availableTaxis;

        public Dispatcher() {
            taxis = new HashSet<Taxi>();
            availableTaxis = new HashSet<Taxi>();
        }

        public synchronized void notifyAvailable(Taxi taxi) {
            availableTaxis.add(taxi);
        }

        public synchronized Image getImage() {
            Image image = new Image();
            for (Taxi t : taxis)
                image.drawMarker(t.getLocation());
            return image;
        }
    }
```

**No Deadlock**

```
class Taxi {
        @GuardedBy("this")
        private Point location, destination;
        private final Dispatcher dispatcher;

        public synchronized Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public synchronized void setLocation(Point location) {
            boolean reachedDestination;
            synchronized (this) {
                this.location = location;
                reachedDestination = location.equals(destination);
            }
            if (reachedDestination)
                dispatcher.notifyAvailable(this);
        }
    }

    class Dispatcher {
        @GuardedBy("this")
        private final Set<Taxi> taxis;
        @GuardedBy("this")
        private final Set<Taxi> availableTaxis;

        public synchronized void notifyAvailable(Taxi taxi) {
            availableTaxis.add(taxi);
        }

        public Image getImage() {
            Set<Taxi> copy;
            synchronized (this) {
                copy = new HashSet<Taxi>(taxis);
            }
            Image image = new Image();
            for (Taxi t : copy)
                image.drawMarker(t.getLocation());
            return image;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Taxi.setLocation` method in the "No Deadlock" code listing shouldn't be `synchronized`.

The [online errata page](https://jcip.net/errata.html) reads:

> p.214 In Listing 10.6, `Taxi.setLocation` should not be a synchronized method. (The synchronized block in its body is correct, however.) (Fixed in 6th printing.)

In the deadlock-prone code, when a thread calls `Taxi.setLocation`, it first acquires the `Taxi` lock. And **while holding the `Taxi` lock**, it proceeds to get the `Dispatcher` lock.

```
Taxi.setLocation

┌----lock Taxi
|  ┌-lock Dispatcher
│  |
|  └-unlock Dispatcher
└----unlock Taxi
```

This pattern is similar to the `LeftRightDeadlock` example with nested lock acquisition.

```java
// Warning: deadlock-prone!
public void leftRight() {
  synchronized (left) {
    synchronized (right) {
      doSomething()
    }
  }
}
```

In the revised version, note the `Taxi` lock is **released before acquiring the `Dispatcher` lock**.

```
Taxi.setLocation

┌----lock Taxi
└----unlock Taxi

┌----lock Dispatcher
└----unlock Dispatcher
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no deadlock in second because getImage not synchronized, so when calling getLocation no lock is held. You're right about the synchronized(this) inside setLocation, it serves no purpose.